# When I use visual studio remote linux to connect to connect to a linux virtual machine, the connection is instability

Tags: linux, visual-studio, vmware, remote-debugging

I use visual studio remote linux  to connect to connect to a linux virtual machine(On VMware).
I can always ping virtual machine's host name succesfule.But when I try to test this connection ,somtime it success,sometime it fail.

Answer (score 0):

Got to your remote machine

```
ps -fux
```

type above command you will see list of processes
kill the one's running .vscode-se***

and try connecting again it will work

Comment: I can't find .vscode-se*** in list of processes。Maybe it is because I use Visual studio but not vscode？

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem,but I don't know why.

At the time I find this problem, I connect to virtual machine by it's hostname (getted by linux command `hostname`).[just like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T02Br.png)

But when I change to connect to virtual machine by it's ip address,this problem is solved.